# Can I link SQL Server to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sql

I would like to link a database with non-spatial data (it is just text and numbers) with a shapefile in QGIS. (Note: it is Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) How do I do that?

If I am able to connect the database can I join both a specific table from SQL with the .shp file using a common ID?

Comment: Are you able to make a connection to your MSSQL database in QGIS? If so, loading the non-spatial table into QGIS will only work if the table has an OBJECTID or other unique Id column, and if the SHP and the MSSQL table have a shared column / key, you should have no problem.

Comment: I am trying to figure that out now. Apparently I can't seem to make a connection. Cant seem to get the correct Provider/DSN and Host from SSMS - do you know where/how I can get that info?

Comment: Can you connect in SSMS? Its the same connection info - don't use Provider/DSN, instead use the HOST option, then with username/password added, click the 'list databases' button to the right to see if your connection works...

Comment: I have connected to the SSMS but i cant seem to load the layer - it keeps saying it 'is an invalid layer'. Does it matter if the Type states 'No Geometry'? There is a column that is the same which is in a text format but not in a OBJECTID format - does that matter?

Comment: @Bernie- It matters if the type states 'No Geometry'. You will not be able to load it into QGIS.